# How to record log of bash script in another script?

Tags: bash

Suppose you have your `foo.sh` script.
And you want to run `foo.sh` from `rc.local`.

How to capture the log of `foo.sh`?

I've tried:

```
#!/bin/sh  
. foo.sh @> /tmp/foo.log    
exit 0
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try the following modification in your script:

```
#!/bin/sh  
. /full/path/to/foo.sh > /tmp/foo.log    
exit 0
```

1. Update your script to include the full path of `foo.sh`
2. Remove the `@`